# Will WaveNet performance suffer to train on /apparently/ sparse signals?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

As you know, WaveNet receives a signal (ie 1D array) as its input.

Let's say I'm training a WaveNet model on a corpus of "fake 2D" arrays of fake depth ten. The nature of my data requires the value at [all but a few of the fake dimension's indices] to equal 0 for the vast majority of the signal's existence:

```
s(0) = 7.0,
s(1) = 9.0,
s(2) to s(9) = 0;
s(10) = 7.1,
s(11) = 8.9,
s(12) to s(19) = 0;
s(20) = 7.2,
s(21) = 8.8,
s(22) to s(29) = 0...
```

The fake indices fill up sequentially. If I were to preserve detail perfectly, I'd set fake depth such that the value at max fake depth index would be nonzero only once throughout the entire corpus. (You can imagine how slicing off the latter end of this fake dimension is almost like lowering the sample rate of an audio file--denuding finer detail).

Is there anything inherent to WaveNet's architecture rendering it unfit to interpret such an *apparently* sparse signal? If so, what model better suits this data of mine?

Answer (score 0):

This potential solution came to me in a dream just now:

> ...A shuffling, then silence on the line. It stretches on. Never
>   wavering, you nonetheless begin to sense Paul McCartney's expectant beam grows
>   stiff from the waiting. I feel bad for him, feel bad for his sincere
>   yet just-as-impossible expectations...
>
> Out from that silence, an answer to my wavenet architecture question
>   jumps out:
>
> **Have the first number of each virtual slice -- before the 0th virtual
>   index -- have that correspond to the number of indices in the slice to
>   come.**

Instead of:

```
s(0) = 7.0,
s(1) = 9.0,
s(2) to s(9) = 0;
s(10) = 7.1,
s(11) = 8.9,
s(12) to s(19) = 0;
s(20) = 7.2,
s(21) = 8.8,
s(22) to s(29) = 0...
```

Have

```
s(0) = 2,
  s(1) = 7.0,
  s(2) = 9.0;
s(3) = 2,
  s(4) = 7.1,
  s(5) = 8.9;
s(6) = 2,
  s(7) = 7.2,
  s(8) = 8.8...
```

`s(0)`, `s(3)`, and `s(6)` are all expressed as ints here for the sake of clarity. They correspond to the number of virtual indices to follow. That is, if there were ten virtual indices at the third slice, `s(6)` instead would equal `10` and not `2`; these ten indices would populate `s(7)` through `s(16)`. Then `s(17)` would convey the number of indices in the fourth slice, and so on.

Is the resulting increase in practical receptive field worth the consequential increase in abstraction?

EDIT:

Update: I don't even need s(0), s(3), and s(6) corresponding to the number of values to come--That very pattern is present implicitly within the signal already. *Just have them equal zero.* That is, just prepend the beginning of each "time slice"--each virtual dimension--with a single zero.

```
s(0) = 0.0,
  s(1) = 7.0,
  s(2) = 9.0;
s(3) = 0.0,
  s(4) = 7.1,
  s(5) = 8.9;
s(6) = 0.0,
  s(7) = 7.2,
  s(8) = 8.8...
```

Doy.